# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `city' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I'm having `belongs_to` / `has_many` relationship between `Trainer` and `Sportists`. I'm trying to loop through their values in `view` like this:

```
<% @sportists.each do |s| %>
 <%= s.name %> <%= s.surname %>
 <%= s.trainer.city %>
<% end %>
```

and the `Sportist` related information works fine, but the `trainers` - doesn't. I get the error given in the title. If I try to do this in `rails console` everything works, so relationships should be set fine.

Things I've tried:

```
<% s.trainers.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.city %>
<% end %>
```

that gives me `undefined method 'trainers'` error, and if I try `s.trainer` I get

`#<TRAINER:0X00000004CE7CB0>`

So what could be the fix?

**EDIT**

My models:

**Trainer**

```
has_many :sportists
belongs_to :team
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sportists, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

**Sportist**

```
belongs_to :trainer
```

**Controller**

```
@sportists = Sportist.all
```

Comment: Post your Model codes.

Comment: @Pavan edited my post with Model information.

Comment: To which `view page` that `code snippet` belongs?

Comment: And also post your controller code.

Comment: @Pavan it belongs to list view. Added edit with the controller bit.

Comment: Do you have any existed records of `sportists`?

Comment: I think that one of your sportists doesn't have a trainer. Check sportists for trainer = nil

Comment: @AntonGrigoryev - Is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `undefined method 'city' for nil:NilClass` in below code:

```
<% @sportists.each do |s| %>
 <%= s.name %> <%= s.surname %>
 <%= s.trainer.city %>
<% end %>
```

which means that there is a `sportists` record which doesn't have `trainer` associated to it. 
So, for that particular sportlist record `s.trainer` is `nil` and you cannot call `city` on `nil` object.

To identify the `sportist` record for which you don't have an associated `trainer`, just update the view code as below:

```
<% @sportists.each do |s| %>
 <%= s.name %> <%= s.surname %>
 <%= s.trainer.try(:city) %>
<% end %>
```

This way even if you don't have an associated `trainer` record, error would not be raised.
In the rendered view, just look for `sportlist` record which doesn't show any `city`, that would be the `sportlist` record without an associated `trainer`.

As for the second error `undefined method 'trainers'` that you received on

```
<% s.trainers.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.city %>
<% end %>
```

sportlist belongs_to `trainer`, you only have dynamic method `trainer` (NOTE singular) available and NOT `trainers` (NOTE plural). Also, `s.trainer` would return a single trainer record so you cannot iterate over it with `each` method as it is not a collection BUT a single record.

**UPDATE**

Ideally, you should not have allowed creation of `sportist` records without a `trainer`.
You should have added an `index` on the foreign key `trainer_id` created on `sportlists` table. **With this you don't even have to use `try` method and your current code would work as it is.**

Comment: I would like to go with what @Anton Grigoryev has said. I would recommend not to use try method and instead use delegate method. It's Rails one of the best practices.

Comment: I don't understand how `delegate` would resolve it. `delegate` would again be calling `trainer.city` i.e. delegated to `trainer`. May be you could explain.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of delegate and avoid use of `try, if and terniary operator`.

Sportist

```
belongs_to :trainer

delegate :city,  to: :trainer, :allow_nil => true
```

You need to make small change to your existing code and it will work smoothly :)

```
<% @sportists.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.name %> <%= s.surname %>
   <%= s.city %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a `sportists` that doesn't have a `trainer`. To avoid this make an `if` condition like this.

```
<% @sportists.each do |s| %>
 <%= s.name %> <%= s.surname %>
 <%= s.trainer.city if s.trianer.present?%>
<% end %>
```

And also setting the validation in the **`Sportist`** model should resolve the empty `trainer_id` values

```
Class Sportist < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :trainer

validates :trainer_id, presence: true

end
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting if condition.

Comment: @Addicted so that it checks whether the associated trainer existed or not.If existed it prints the trainers city value.

Comment: I was trying to make a point that we should not unnecessarily use if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code

```
   <% @sportists.each do |s| %>
     <%= s.name %> <%= s.surname %>
     <%= s.trainer.city %>
   <% end %>
```

with

```
   <% @sportists.each do |s| %>
     <%= s.name %> <%= s.surname %>
     <%= s.trainer.present? ? s.trainer.city : "No City Found"  %>
   <% end %>
```

This will stop the code to throw nil errors